# How to run a Matlab R2018b script in Spyder (python 3.10) from Anaconda3?

Tags: python, matlab, windows-10, spyder, anaconda3

I tried run my *.m script (written by Matlab R2018b) from spyder (anaconda3 & python version 3.10 on windows 10). I got compatibility problem of python & Matlab. I installed trial Matlab R2022a but it didn't solve my problem. I also reduced the python version from 3.10 to 3.6 to be compatible with Matlab R2018b, as I saw in some advices in stack overflow.
However, this version reduction took too much time on my laptop and didn't solve the problem.
I am using Computer Vision, Image Processing, Optimization, and Statistics & Machine Learning tools boxes of Matlab R2022a (trial version) or R2018b.
Many thanks for your helpful comments.

Best regards,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just to inform readers that the problem is related to before writing any code ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a good idea, The python code looks like:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.simple_script(nargout=0)
eng.quit()
```

And another way:

it works in anaconda spyder but u gave to install anaconda 3.4 or below for Matlab 2016b or according to the python package present in Matlab.
you can check the python package available in Matlab from matlabroot\extern\engines\python path
for safe side install anaconda 2.7 or 3.0 and

goto> anaconda prompt and type

cd "matlabroot\extern\engines\python"

python setup.py install

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already done what you wrote. The problem is that my python is 3.10 which is not a compatible version to use for running: matlab.engine.start_matlab() since my Matlab version is R2018b. By reduction Python version to 3.6, the problem hasn't been solved. The problem is realised when installing by "python setup.py install".

Answer (score 0):

Python has an initial configuration so that the system recognizes it, and we can call it.

Did you set the Python 3.6 environment in the setting?

Comment: Sure, that is a good idea. Thanks. My system is still downgrading python 3.10 to python 3.6 ... 20% is left ...

Comment: Strangely, the python could not be downgraded! I set python=3.6, my system, after more than 72h working on downgrading, shows the python version is still 3.10! I think it is better to reinstall anaconda with a version which is compatible to matlab 2018b and start all thing from scracth ... 

Comment: @user173539 I agree with you; it seems that there is a problem in setting it up, delete it and install it again and make sure to make the appropriate Python settings for MATLAB; I mean adding it to Environment